# Can I re-used Yankee Candle glass bottle for food?

Tags: food-safety, food-water-storage, honey

I have a few used Yankee Candle glass bottles.  I am wondering if I can use them for storing honey or other food items?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because food safety isn't on topic here.